# Accessing struct members and arrays of structs from LLVM IR

Tags: c++, llvm, jit

If I have a C++ program that declares a `struct`, say:

```
struct S {
    short s;
    union U {
        bool b;
        void *v;
    };
    U u;
};
```

and I generate some LLVM IR via the LLVM C++ API to mirror the C++ declaration:

```
vector<Type*> members;
members.push_back( IntegerType::get( ctx, sizeof( short ) * 8 ) );
// since LLVM doesn't support unions, just use an ArrayType that's the same size
members.push_back( ArrayType::get( IntegerType::get( ctx, 8 ), sizeof( S::U ) ) );

StructType *const llvm_S = StructType::create( ctx, "S" );
llvm_S->setBody( members );
```

How can I ensure that `sizeof(S)` in the C++ code is the same size as the `StructType` in LLVM IR code?  Same for the offsets of the individual members, i.e., `u.b`.

It's also the case that I have an array of `S` allocated in C++:

```
S *s_array = new S[10];
```

and I pass `s_array` to LLVM IR code in which I access individual elements of the array.  In order for this to work, `sizeof(S)` has to be the same in both C++ and LLVM IR so this:

```
%elt = getelementptr %S* %ptr_to_start, i64 1
```

will access `s_array[1]` properly.

When I compile and run the program below, it outputs:

```
sizeof(S) = 16
allocSize(S) = 10
```

The problem is that LLVM is missing 6 bytes of padding between `S::s` and `S::u`.  The C++ compiler makes the `union` start on a 8-byte-aligned boundary whereas LLVM does not.

I was playing around with `DataLayout`. For my machine [Mac OS X 10.9.5, g++ Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)], if I print the data layout string, I get:

```
e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128
```

If I force-set the data layout to:

```
e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128-a:64
```

where the addition is of `a:64` which means that an object of aggregate type aligns on a 64-bit boundary, then I get the *same* size.  So why isn't the default data layout correct?

---

## Complete working program below

```
// LLVM
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/MCJIT.h>
#include <llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Type.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>

// standard
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace llvm;

struct S {
    short s;
    union U {
        bool b;
        void *v;
    };
    U u;
};

ExecutionEngine* createEngine( Module *module ) {
    InitializeNativeTarget();
    InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();

    unique_ptr<Module> u( module );
    EngineBuilder eb( move( u ) );
    string errStr;
    eb.setErrorStr( &errStr );
    eb.setEngineKind( EngineKind::JIT );
    ExecutionEngine *const exec = eb.create();
    if ( !exec ) {
        cerr << "Could not create ExecutionEngine: " << errStr << endl;
        exit( 1 );
    }
    return exec;
}

int main() {
    LLVMContext ctx;

    vector<Type*> members;
    members.push_back( IntegerType::get( ctx, sizeof( short ) * 8 ) );
    members.push_back( ArrayType::get( IntegerType::get( ctx, 8 ), sizeof( S::U ) ) );

    StructType *const llvm_S = StructType::create( ctx, "S" );
    llvm_S->setBody( members );

    Module *const module = new Module( "size_test", ctx );
    ExecutionEngine *const exec = createEngine( module );
    DataLayout const *const layout = exec->getDataLayout();
    module->setDataLayout( layout );

    cout << "sizeof(S) = " << sizeof( S ) << endl;
    cout << "allocSize(S) = " << layout->getTypeAllocSize( llvm_S ) << endl;

    delete exec;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about [getTypeAllocSize()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a1d6fcc02e91ba24510aba42660c90e29) ?

Comment: OK, that tells me how big it is. In this case, the sizes do _not_ match. So how do I make them match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the original answer is the correct answer to the "pre-edit" question, I'm writing a completely new answer to the new question (and my guess that the structs are not actually the same was pretty good).

The problem isn't about `DataLayout` as such [but you will need the DataLayout to solve the problem, so you need to update the code to create the module before starting to make LLVM-IR], but the fact that you are combining a `union` that has alignment restrictions in a `struct` with lesser alignment restrictions:

```
struct S {
    short s;        // Alignment = 2 
    union U {    
        bool b;     // Alignment = 1
        void *v;    // Alignment = 4 or 8
    };
    U u;            // = Alignment = 4 or 8
};
```

Now in your LLVM code-gen:

```
members.push_back( IntegerType::get( ctx, sizeof( short ) * 8 ) );
members.push_back( ArrayType::get( IntegerType::get( ctx, 8 ), sizeof( S::U ) ) );
```

The second element in your struct is a `char dummy[sizeof(S::U)]`, which has an alignment requirement of 1. So, of course, LLVM will align the `struct` differently than the C++ compiler that has a stricter alignment criteria.

In this particular case, using a `i8 *` (aka `void *`) in place of the array of `i8` would do the trick [obviously with the relevant `bitcast` to translate to the other types as necessary when accessing the value of `b`]

To fix this, in a completely generic way, you need to produce a `struct` consisting of the element with the largest alignment requirement in the `union`, and then pad it with enough `char` elements to make up for the largest size.

I'm going to have something to eat now, but I will get back with some code that solves it properly, but it's a bit more complex than I originally thought.

Here is the `main` posted above modified to use a pointer instead of `char` array:

```
int main() {
    LLVMContext ctx;

    vector<Type*> members;
    members.push_back( IntegerType::get( ctx, sizeof( short ) * 8 ) );
    members.push_back( PointerType::getUnqual( IntegerType::get( ctx, 8 ) ) );

    StructType *const llvm_S = StructType::create( ctx, "S" );
    llvm_S->setBody( members );

    Module *const module = new Module( "size_test", ctx );
    ExecutionEngine *const exec = createEngine( module );
    DataLayout const *const layout = exec->getDataLayout();
    module->setDataLayout( *layout );

    cout << "sizeof(S) = " << sizeof( S ) << endl;
    cout << "allocSize(S) = " << layout->getTypeAllocSize( llvm_S ) << endl;

    delete exec;
    return 0;
}
```

There are also some tiny changes to cover the fact that `setDataLayout` has changed between your version of LLVM and the one I'm using.

And finally a generic version that allows any type to be used:

```
Type* MakeUnionType( Module* module, LLVMContext& ctx, vector<Type*> um )
{
    const DataLayout dl( module );
    size_t maxSize = 0;
    size_t maxAlign = 0;
    Type*  maxAlignTy = 0;

    for( auto m : um )
    {
        size_t sz = dl.getTypeAllocSize( m );
        size_t al = dl.getPrefTypeAlignment( m );
        if( sz > maxSize ) 
            maxSize = sz;
        if( al > maxAlign) 
        {
            maxAlign = al;
            maxAlignTy = m;
        }
    }
    vector<Type*> sv = { maxAlignTy };
    size_t mas = dl.getTypeAllocSize( maxAlignTy );
    if( mas < maxSize )
    {
        size_t n = maxSize - mas;
        sv.push_back(ArrayType::get( IntegerType::get( ctx, 8 ), n ) );
    }
    StructType* u = StructType::create( ctx, "U" );
    u->setBody( sv );
    return u;
}

int main() {
    LLVMContext ctx;

    Module *const module = new Module( "size_test", ctx );
    ExecutionEngine *const exec = createEngine( module );
    DataLayout const *const layout = exec->getDataLayout();
    module->setDataLayout( *layout );

    vector<Type*> members;
    members.push_back( IntegerType::get( ctx, sizeof( short ) * 8 ) );
    vector<Type*> unionMembers = { PointerType::getUnqual( IntegerType::get( ctx, 8 ) ), 
                   IntegerType::get( ctx, 1 )  };
    members.push_back( MakeUnionType( module, ctx, unionMembers ) );

    StructType *const llvm_S = StructType::create( ctx, "S" );
    llvm_S->setBody( members );

    cout << "sizeof(S) = " << sizeof( S ) << endl;
    cout << "allocSize(S) = " << layout->getTypeAllocSize( llvm_S ) << endl;

    delete exec;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in both cases, you need a `bitcast` operation to convert the address of `b` - and in the second case, you also need a bitcast to convert the `struct` into `void *`, but assuming you actually want generic `union` support, that would be how you'd have to do it anyway.

A complete piece of code to generate a `union` type can be found here, which is for my Pascal compiler's `variant` [which is Pascal's way to make a `union`]:

https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/types.cpp#L525
and code generation including bitcast:
https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/expr.cpp#L520

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. :) But why are there discrepancies in the two versions of code? For example, this version checks `mas < maxSize` whereas the Pascal version checks `maxAlignElt != maxSizeElt`.

Comment: Because the end result is the same - if the largest aligned element is >=  maxSize then we don't need padding. If the element with the max alignment is same as max size element, we don't need padding. [I think my compiler code can be simplified, to be fair, but I'm in the middle of fixing some other stuff, and I don't want to break things just to remove three lines of code that isn't strictly necessary but works]

Comment: As an aside, if I wanted to have my `struct` contain, say, `std::string`, I'd prefer _not_ to have to elaborately describe its layout (that would be implementation-dependent anyway). I think it would be possible to do something similar to `union` by having a template struct containing a type T (again, say, `std::string`) and figure out its offset and then constructing a `StructType` accordingly. Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure, you'd have to figure out the alignment and then find another type that matches that alignment [assuming you don't care about accessing the content of `std::string`]. You can find the alignment using `alignof`, but I can't figure a way to SET the alignment of a member in a struct.

Comment: You wouldn't have to set it. If your probe struct is `struct { char c; T t; } s;` you can use `offsetof` to know what the alignment is (in pre-C++11). You then pick a built-in type having a matching alignment (which you could pre-probe for all the built-in C++ types) and use that in `StructType` then just fill the rest with padding.

Comment: Yes, something like that. (Since LLVM requries C++11 since 3.5, I'd use `alignof` - no need to complicate things unnecessarily). And you can probably make a table of types with various alignments and just look up the relevant type for a given alignment.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `DataLayout` is to know the alignment of elements. If you don't need to know the size, alignment or offsets of elements in your code [and LLVM doesn't really have a useful way beyond GEP instruction to find the offset, so you can pretty much ignore the offset part], you won't need a datalayout until you come to execute (or generate object file) from the IR.

(I did have some very interesting bugs from trying to compile 32-bit code with a 64-bit "native" datalayout when I implemented the -m32 switch for my compiler - not a good idea to switch DataLayout in the middle of compilation, which I did because I used the "default" one, and then set a different one when it came to creating the actual object file).

Comment: My question said I need to get the sizes and alignments correct.

Comment: But still, the DataLayout only matters at the point of generating code or getting the size, so I think you need to show a bit more code, or explain a bit more exactly what DOESN'T work. How is it wrong? What happens, and how is it different from what you expect? What is the `sizeof(S)` in C++, and what is `DataLayout::getTypeAllocSize(t)`? What is `DataLayout::getPrefTypeAlignment(x);`, where `x` is the elements of `t`?

Comment: My actual struct is a bit more involved than the toy example shown here. Suffice it to say that `sizeof(S)` < `DataLayout::getTypeAllocSize(s)` where `s` is an LLVM instance of an equivalent `StructType`. I need the latter to be the same size as the former so C++ objects created by the C++ compiler can be used by LLVM IR JIT'd code.

And the whole point of this is to generated JIT'd LLVM IR code that can interoperate with C++ compiler generated code.

Comment: I understand that, but it really needs to be a reproducible example of it going wrong in your question to be able to give more help than "you need to have the same DataLayout for both cases". (Including the possibility that for some reason your struct isn't ACTUALLY identical between the two cases!)

Comment: OK, there's a complete working program that shows the size discrepancy.